# How to initialise method of superclass in constructor of subclass

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, subclass, superclass

SuperClass

```
public class Kola {
    int id;
    Put put = new Put(id, id);
    public Kola(int id1) {
        id1=0;
    }
  public int prelazenje(int p){
     return p = (int)(5 + (Math.random() * (10 - 5)));
  }
  public int paljenje (int pa){
    return pa=(int)(5 + (Math.random() * (10 - 5)));
  }
  public void start(){
  }
}
```

SubClass

```
public class Smer1 extends Kola implements Runnable {
    Thread objekat1;    
    public Smer1(int ) {
        super();
        objekat1 = new Thread(objekat1);
        objekat1.start();   
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Problem is:

In superclass constructor to initialize Kola (forward her Put, and the identifier) is a method by which the thread is run (by calling the method start) has run method calls the method of "paljenje" from the class of Kola, you need synchronized access to the Put and the access to the variable; After that start the method of "Prelazenje";
And again you need synchronized access to the road, but then again update the variables.

Comment: Problem is:

In superclass constructor to initialize Kola (forward her Put, and the identifier) is a method by which the thread is run (by calling
the method start) has run method calls the method of "paljenje" from the class of Kola, you need synchronized access to the Put and the access to the variable; After that start the method of "Prelazenje"; And again you need synchronized access to the road, but then again update the variables.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking.  I don't see `Put` class. What do you need to sync ? (See asking in help and [MCVE])

Comment: Your code does not make sense to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You do **not** initialize **methods**. Methods do not have state; you only **invoke** them.

In other words: the behavior of what a method **does** depends on the **parameters** it is receiving; and the **fields** that it has access to.

When you want to make sure that a call to the method from your superclass gives the correct result - then you only have to make sure that you setup the **fields** of your superclass accordingly.

For now, your problem is **very** simple: your child class calls **super()**; so you need a constructor that doesn't take any argument. But your super class only has **one** constructor - that takes an argument!

And right there, another bug:

```
objekat1 = new Thread(objekat1);
```

That translates to:

```
objekat1 = new Thread(null);
```

(because objekat1 is null "on the right hand side of =".)

And of course: your methods prelazenje() and palenje() ... only depend on their **arguments**. So, no matter how you init your superclass, those methods will **always** do the same thing given the same parameter!

So, honestly, the **only** answer that makes sense here is: please stop whatever you are doing right now. Step back. Before you should even think about runnables and threads, you really have to **learn** about the basics.

Your code shows that you have no idea about a lot of important things in Java; and at the same time, you are trying to building something complicated. That **will** not work. Because you have **no** clue what you are doing.

And we can't help with that part, only you can.

Comment: Well, there are other problems as well. E.g.: `objekat1 = new Thread(objekat1);` ... or `public Kola(int id1) {
        id1=0;
    }`, not to mention `public Smer1(int ) {` which won't even compile but may be a copy&paste thing ...

Comment: Yep, figured that in the meantime.

Comment: +1 for the clear words. I'd like to add the hint for OP: If you are seeking help in an international forum, please name your vars and methods in english. It just makes it easier to follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Fildor That is the nice thing when already hitting the daily-200-limit around noon time. One can step back, be a bit more relaxed; and spent some more minutes to tell a newbie some truths; instead of the usual downvote-closerequest-next process.